# Can I target jQuery render() for specific id's on page? Assistly Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, contacts

I have started using Assistly for managed customer support (incredible by the way if you haven't checked on it: [www.assistly.com](http://www.assistly.com)).

One feature they include is automated contact form creation and delivery from there site. While they provide you with code to embed, it is not very '2011' friendly is supposed to be placed wherever you want a rendered email icon.

The JavaScript to include(which calls lightbox and assistly code) is [found here](https://d3j15y3zsn7b4t.cloudfront.net/assets/widget_embed_libraries.jsgz?1316066361).

The code to embed as it stands is:

```
<script>
new ASSISTLY.Widget({ 
        version: 1, 
        site: 'help.site.com', 
        port: '80', 
        type: 'email', 
        displayMode: 1,  //0 for popup, 1 for lightbox
        features: {  
        },  
        fields: { 
                ticket: { 
                        // desc: '',
// labels_new: '',
// priority: '',
// subject: ''
                }, 
                interaction: { 
                        // email: '',
// name: ''
                }, 
                email: { 
                        //subject: '', 
                        //body: '' 
                }, 
                customer: { 
                        // company: '',
// desc: '',
// first_name: '',
// last_name: '',
// title: ''
                } 
        } 
}).render();  
</script>
```

I would like to be able to create links (or images) across my page and have each one reference the code above to create the Assistly contact box. Has anybody had luck with this before?

### update

This question reflects my own but I do not believe the answer given by the CSR is correct (atleast in my tested code. The `render()` function is still called so the email icon is present and a text overlay just sits on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am sure there are other methods. I instead utilized existing jquery Colorbox calls we have on our site (using iFrame) and pointed the target URL to a defined Assistly page:

http://SITE.assistly.com/customer/widget/emails/new